# How to pass a value to a strongly typed view in asp mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In one of my actions I've got this:

```
ViewBag.Val = "a val";
View();
```

The associated view:

```
@{
  Model.Attr = ViewBag.Val;
}
```

Exception details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

...

```
Line 27: Model.Attr = ViewBag.Val;
```

Is this the real line causing troubles, if it is how can you pass a value to a view and set a model attribute to that value.

**Edit:**

I've loged the execution, the assignment works fine:

get action:

```
var Obj = MyModel();
Obj.Attr = 123;
return View(Obj);
```

view:

```
<p>@Model.Attr</p> // shows 123
```

but on post action that receives MyModel, MyModel.Atrr is 0.

Why this is happening and how to fix it.

**Edit 2**

The model the view is bound to is the model that is expected to be procesed on an post action and is the model that i want to assign the value on the view or on the previous (get) action. I just want to pass a value 'a' from 'get action' to view, assign 'model.a' = 'a', and then process the 'model' (with 'a' attached to it) on 'post action'.

What i can tell from the log is that the model bound to the view and the model you pass to the view from 'get action' are diferent instances.

Comment: What is your model? Does it make sense to touch the model within view?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass an object to the view, so `Model` is null, so trying to write to the `Attr` property threw.

Pass something here:

```
ViewBag.Val = "a val";
View(new SomeModelTypeYadaYadaThatCorrespondsToTheView());
```

Michal Klouda's comment is also correct, your going about this the wrong way. The values you need to populate should be done when the model is constructed, **not** during the view render.

Comment: No, its a strongly typed view, some attributes must come from the controller and asigned like in the post. My bad i typed 'static' insted of 'strongly' in the title.

Comment: @user1108631 Ok then my original response is correct - You need to pass a model object to the view.

Comment: Apparently it is not being assigned to the model the view is typed to.

Comment: @user1108631 I get the impression you do not understand what I am telling you. Just because a view is declared strongly typed doesn't mean you can omit passing it an instance of the model! Create a new instance and pass it to the view, and it will work. I promise!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this to your .cshtml file (I don't think you have it):

```
    @model YourModelNameSpace.YourModel
```

This will give you a strongly-typed Model that isn't null.

Comment: @user1108631 so what's null, then?  Is it the model or "val"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return** the View in your Action method and pass the Model.

```
ViewBag.Val = "a val";
return View(YourModel);
```